# Lookup with SSJS in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

```javascript
<script runat="server">

  Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");

  var str = Attribute.GetValue('Test_JSON'); 
  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(str);
  var val = obj.idSave;
  var CodeDe = DataExtension.Init("TbTest");
  var Code = CodeDe.Rows.Lookup(["SECTOR"],[val]);
  Variable.SetValue("@val", val); 

</script> 
%%=v(@val)=%%
```

I have a process  where we receive a json through field in data extension from another system and for each a data, need to sent a text (same text for all in same value in json) that  is present in another data extension called here TbTest with two columns: idSave and text1;

How can I use the lookup in ssjs to get the value from the 'TbTest'. I think it's possible, but I'm not able to do this

for example, if the json (obj.idSave) will be 'sales' I have a row in 'TbTest' with: `idSave = sales and text1 = 'cancelled';`  I need to put the column 'text1' in HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking to do is almost there - but I would remove the Core library from your script as it is not needed and can cause unnecessary processing and load time, leading to a delay in send time.

See below for example SSJS solution:

```js
<script runat="server">
  var str = Attribute.GetValue('Test_JSON'); 
  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(str);
  var val = obj.idSave;
  Variable.SetValue("@val", val); 

  var text = Platform.Function.Lookup('TbTest','text1','idSave',val)
  Variable.SetValue('@text',text);

</script> 
Val: %%=v(@val)=%%<br>
Text: %%=v(@text)=%%
```

That being said, if you are just looking to parse the JSON, but are more comfortable in AMPScript, you can cut out the lookup in SSJS and do it in AMPscript:

```js
<script runat="server">
  var str = Attribute.GetValue('Test_JSON'); 
  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(str);
  var val = obj.idSave;
  Variable.SetValue("@val", val); 
</script> 
%%[ SET @text = Lookup("TbTest", "Text1","idSave",@val) ]%%
val: %%=v(@val)=%% <br>
text: %%=v(@text)=%%
```

Or you can also skip SSJS and use GTL with AMPScript (I shudder every time I say it, but it IS a viable option).

```js
%%[SET @JSON = AttributeValue("Test_JSON")]%%
  {{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows=1}}
    {{.data}}
      { "target" : "@JSON" }
    {{/data}}
%%[ SET @val = TreatAsContent('{{idSave}}')
    SET @text = Lookup("TbTest", "Text1","idSave",@val) 
]%%
val: %%=v(@val)=%% <br>
text: %%=v(@text)=%%
```

Comment: i need to pay a coffee for you