# Break ampscript resultset when spaces are found and store them in separate variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

Currently I have script to fetch values from a DE

```
SET @retrieveRequest = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty (@retrieveRequest, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[Testing_CW_Unsub]")

AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","ID")
```

But above code gets all the DE rows into single Field variable.

```
Set @Field1= FIELD(@currentProp ,"Name")
Set @Field2= FIELD(@currentProp ,"Value")
```

ResultSet : %%=v(@Field2)=%% fetches all the declared values from DE into single variable.

```
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","id")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","email")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","Status")
```

I would like to break the values as soon as space is found within result and store them in separate ampscript variables

Comment: Just curious but why are you doing a retrieve request instead of a lookup? There is options to do what you are saying, but I feel like its not really necessary because via a lookuprows or lookuporderedrows you can then grab each field value directly by the associated field name and not need to rely on spaces as delimiters or otherwise separate values manually.

Comment: basically, I have created ampscript content block and then fetching that content block in script activity to be further used within automation.

Comment: But why not use lookuprows still? If anything it would likely be faster being pulled into a script activity or in an email and its simpler than utilizing the built in API functions.

Comment: I am asking, as I feel like you are running into an XYProblem (https://xyproblem.info/) in this when there may be a simpler or alternative solution that can get you there in a different route.

Comment: Maybe I am not aware how to use lookuprows directly in a content block when the block is not used within an email. could you please provide link to an example where data can be populated within landing page or can be fetched in a content block (WHEN CLOUDPAGE OR CONTENT BLOCK IS NOT USED IN AN EMAIL) . as I highlighted the ampscript is used in an automation and the automation has one query to inject data into data extension and then the script is fetching records from DE. I tried lookup but need to initiate DEor attributevalue to get DE values which is not an option when not using within email

Comment: chances are you don't even need ampscript but can work directly inside the automation; ampscript and ssjs platform functions can basically do the same here, just the syntax differs; check an example of ssjs platform lookup: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330463/lookup-with-ssjs-in-marketing-cloud ... and lookuprows via ssjs platform: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358825/how-to-check-if-data-in-data-extension-is-present-or-clear-by-someone-accidently/359957#359957 - lookups work outside emails just fine; you just don't have stuff like `_subscriber` context.